# Extract data from HTML table to email via PHP

Tags: php, html, extract

I have a table in HTML that has some input fields in it (just the standard stuff - it's an order form) and all I am trying to do is extract the data so that I can insert it in to an email.

I have got everything else to work except for the extraction of the data from the table which I am posting to a php email function.

I have searched google for all possible solutions (jQuery, javascript etc) but I haven't found a suitable solution.  The closest I got was by simply using `$(this).html()` but it doesn't extract the input values.

I feel this should be a really simple solution but I can find it.

Here is an example of my table with some dummy data:

```
<table id="order-table">
            <tr>
                 <th>Product Name</th> 
                 <th>Quantity</th>
                 <th>X</th>
                 <th>Unit Price</th>
                 <th>=</th>
                 <th style="text-align: right; padding-right: 30px;">Totals</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="product-title">Dell R720 Xeon Server</em></td>
                <td class="qty"><input type="text" class="qty-input"></input></td>
                <td class="times">X</td>
                <td class="price-per-unit">£<span>1006</span></td>
                <td class="equals">=</td>
                <td class="row-total"><input type="text" class="row-total-input" disabled="disabled"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="product-title">VMWare Standard</em></td>
                <td class="qty"><input type="text" class="qty-input"></input></td>
                <td class="times">X</td>
                <td class="price-per-unit">£<span>306</span></td>
                <td class="equals">=</td>
                <td class="row-total"><input type="text" class="row-total-input" disabled="disabled"></input></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" style="text-align: right;">
                    ORDER SUBTOTAL: <input type="text" class="total-box" value="£0" id="product-subtotal" disabled="disabled"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Why don't you use a form or do you wanna do it with AJAX?

Comment: I dont mind either way.  All I am trying to do is create a simple order form that, when submitted, gets emailed to a recipient.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use a form and name (all) your input fields.

#### Naming your field names will be important for this example.

Naming an input field:

```
<input type="text" name="qty_input_odd" class="qty-input">
```

Then in your handler, you would use the inputs' variable like so:

```
$qty_input_odd=$_POST['qty_input_odd'];
```

and the same for the other fields.

Then you can send all that information to your Email and a copy to your client if required.

You can also avoid having to set your input variables by using a `foreach`.

For example:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $message .= "$key: $val\n";
}
```

Full example handler:

```
<?php

$subject = "Form submission";
$sender = preg_replace("/[\r\n,;]/", "", $_POST['email']);
$to = "email@example.com";

$headers = "From: $sender" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $to" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

$redirect = "http://www.example.com/thank_you.php";
$message = "Submitted data:" . "\n\n";
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $message .= "$key: $val\n";
}

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header("Location: $redirect");
// You can use header or echo, but not both
// echo "Message sent";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's serialize and ajax methods:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Serialize lets you serialize all inputs on the page with something like:

```
var formParams = $('#order-table').serialize();
```

and the ajax method lets you pass that data to the server:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: formParams,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, from what I can see on the jQuery site, won't that just give me the inputs?  I need to get the data from the whole table including inputs.  Is that possible?

Comment: So...are you trying to pass both the values from the inputs as well as some of the values inside table cells?  If that is the case, it would be useful to understand why you would want to pass un-editable data from the page.